# Can Marmalade be used to build for the web? Not only web mobile apps?

Tags: html, web, marmalade

What I mean is, can I use it to deploy to google chrome store, facebook or my own website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the web marmalade, then yes you can. Just remove the marmalade files and use your HTML5 code. You might need to change it a bit.
If you're asking about marmalade's official support, no they don't support it (as far as I know).